# display part of a webpage javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

Looking for a javascript method to display a webpage.  Similar to an iframe, but in javascript. 
1. Something like this:

```
    var location = "www.example.com"
    javascript method = location
```

This would display a webpage inside another webpage.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. By js its possible. you create an xmlhttprequest, and put its response to a div. But ofcourse, same origin policy applies.

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

     var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
     var target = '/mylocalsite.aspx';
     req.open( 'GET', encodeURI( target ), true );
     req.onreadystatechange = function () {
         if ( req.readyState == 4 ) {
             document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = req.responseText;
         }
     };
         req.send( null );

</script>
```

But I'll prefer an iframe

Comment: Thank you, I hope other people see this.